# Why am I getting a space in between 2 array elements?

Tags: string, vba

More specifically, why am I getting a space between strarray(1) and strarray(2) in newFilename? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim orgFilename As String
Dim temp As String
Dim strarray(3) As String
Dim newFilename As String

orgFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All files (*.), *.", Title:="Please select a file")


temp = Mid$(orgFilename, InStrRev(orgFilename, "\") + 1)
strarray(1) = Left(orgFilename, InStrRev(orgFilename, "\"))
strarray(2) = "processed_"
strarray(3) = temp
newFilename = Join(strarray)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join adds spaces by default.
Check out the first paragraph in this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164507%28v=office.10%29.aspx

> The Join function takes an array of strings and returns a concatenated
>   string. By default it adds a space between each element of the string,
>   but you can specify a different delimiter.

instead use

```
newFilename = Join(strarray, "")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the behavior of Join() : http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter

Try

```
newFilename = Join(strarray, "")
```